# Daemon won't kill children that are reading from a named pipe

Tags: linux, bash, unix, daemon, named-pipes

I've written this bash daemon that keeps an eye on a named pipe, logs everything it sees on a file named `$LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE`, and it also creates a filtered version of it in `$ACTIONABLE_LOG_FILE`:

```
while true
do
    DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
    cat $NAMED_PIPE | tee -a "$LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE" | grep -P -v "$EXCEPTIONS" >> "$ACTIONABLE_LOG_FILE"
done
pkill -P $$  # Here it's where it should kill it's children
exit 0
```

When the daemon is running, this is how the process table looks:

```
/bin/sh the_daemon.sh
 \_ cat the_fifo_queue
 \_ tee -a log_file.20150807
 \_ grep -P -v "regexp" > filtered_log_file
```

The problem is that when I kill the daemon (SIGTERM), the cat, the tee, and the grep processes that where spawned by the daemon are not collected by the parent. Instead, they become orphans and keep on waiting for input on the named pipe.

Once the FIFO receives some input, then they process that input as instructed and die.

How can I make the daemon kill its children before dying? Why aren't they dying with `pkill -P $$`?

Comment: How are you creating the fifo and writing to it?

Comment: "*that where spawned by the daemon are not collected by the parent*"  why do you expect they were to be collected?

Comment: "*Why aren't they dying with `pkill -P $$`?*" because the statement is never issued, as you sent the script a `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to setup a signal handler for your script which kills all members of its process group (its children) in case the script itself gets signalled:

```
#!/bin/bash

function handle_sigterm()
{
  pkill -P $$
  exit 0
}

trap handle_sigterm SIGTERM 

while true
do
  DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
  cat $NAMED_PIPE | tee -a "$LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE" | grep -P -v "$EXCEPTIONS" >> "$ACTIONABLE_LOG_FILE"
done

handle_sigterm

exit 0
```

---

*Update:*

As per [*pilcrow*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886741/deamon-wont-kill-children-children-are-reading-form-a-named-pipe/31893171?noredirect=1#comment51703117_31893171) replace

```
cat $NAMED_PIPE | tee -a "$LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE" | grep -P -v "$EXCEPTIONS" >> "$ACTIONABLE_LOG_FILE"
```

by

```
cat $NAMED_PIPE | tee -a "$LOG_FILE_BASENAME.$DATE" | grep -P -v "$EXCEPTIONS" >> "$ACTIONABLE_LOG_FILE" &
wait $!
```

Comment: I suggest you background that pipeline and `wait $!` to allow the script to terminate immediately upon receipt of a TERM, rather than when the pipeline finishes.  (Otherwise the `trap` won't spring until the shell is between commands.)